# Is it possible to create a proxy server for any application?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, man-in-the-middle

I've been trying to create a proxy server to analyze TCP packages sent between my computer and a game server.
Now I know that you can do this kind of stuff with Wireshark, but I want to understand the logic of it and how the connections are made.

My main question is that I don't know where to start from. I have the server IP and port from Process Explorer and have the basic socket programming knowledge in python, but as I said, I don't know what to code.

Am I supposed to write a socket that hijacks the incoming TCP connection and forward it to my localhost? but then how would my client send data to server?

As you can see, I'm a bit lost, and I would be very happy if someone could put me in a correct path (what should I research?).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just run `tcpdump` on your client if you want to analyze TCP packets flowing from your client to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a useful tools can help you: [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) and [netfilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter). Using this, you can  hijacks the incoming TCP connection and forward it to your localhost easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and get back to you.